# Calculating Road Distance on the fly

Tags: .net, google-maps, dictionary, bing-maps, distance

WE would like to develop an application to calculate road distance on server side using .NET. We need to compare road distance from Address A to various cities and identify nearest city. I am not sure if there is any Zip to Zip road distance database available. We need to process more than 100 records in a query so performance is critical issue even if we use very fast API unless they provide some way to calculate it in bulk using a single request.

Does anyone know a possible tool to explore that would make this task easier

Comment: Can't you use the Google Maps api?

Comment: I don't think it supports API to calculate distance from bulk locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MapQuest API to achieve this. It seems really working well so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent already i would try and implement it myself on the server side. Scraping a website will be too slow and i dont know of a way to make bulk requests.

I would calculate the distance between zips like this [Using longitude and lattitude](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-do-i-determine-the-distance-between-zip-codes-using-c/634).

Now your second problem is you need longitude and lattitude values for your zips. Here is the best free source of longitude and lattidude of the zip codes in the USA  [zip codes as long and lattitude](http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/)

I tested it out with NYC and philly and cross referenced it via bing and google maps, seems pretty accurate.

Comment: Thanks Bob! We have been using suggested approach since long, We need road distance which can not be calculated through any logic.